# How to print probability for repeated measures logistic regression?

Tags: binary, sas, probability

I would like SAS to print the probability of my binary dependent variable occurring (“Calliphoridae” a particular fly family being present (1) or not (0), at a specific instance for my continuous independent variable (“degree_index” that was recorded from .055 to 2.89, but can be continuously recorded past 2.89 and always increases as time goes on) using Proc GENMOD.  **How do I change my code to print the probability**, for example, that Calliphoridae is present at degree_index=.1?
My example code is:

```
proc genmod data=thesis descending ;
class Body_number ;
model Calliphoridae = degree_index / dist=binomial link=logit ; 
repeated subject=Body_number/ type=cs;
estimate 'degreeindex=.1' intercept 1 degree_index 0 /exp;
estimate 'degree_index=.2' intercept 1 degree_index .1 /exp;run;
```

I get an output for the contrast estimate results as mean estimate at degree_index=.1 is ..99; degree_index=.2 is .98.

Comment: http://www.stat.sc.edu/~hansont/stat704/chapter14a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is correctly modeling the probability...I just didn't include the square of

the degree-day index. If you do, it allows the probability to increase and decrease. I

realized this when I did the probability by hand

(e^-1.1307x+.2119)/(1+e^-1.1307x+.2119) to verify that this really was modeling

probability when y=1 for the mean estimates at specific x values...and then I realized that it is

fitting a regression line and cannot increase and decrease because there is only

one x value.   http://www.stat.sc.edu/~hansont/stat704/chapter14a.pdf